# JPA event listener

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, datetime, spring-data-jpa

I need to build an application that gets records from database, equales to some value and if it returns `true` it will do someee action. I was wondering if JPA can do something like that.

I have an entity `Game`:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Game {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Game() {

    }

    @OneToOne
    private Team teamBlue;

    @OneToOne
    private Team teamRed;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm:ss yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
}
```

and `GameRepository` which returns the `Game`:

```
@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends JpaRepository<Game, Long> {
    @Override
    Optional<Game> findById(Long aLong);
}
```

I want to check if `LocalDateTime` value from `Game` equals to the current `LocalDateTime` (`LocalDateTime.now()`) and if it does, do some action.
Of course I could use `@Scheduled` and call method every 1 hour, but I wonder if what I am describing is feasible.

Short summary:

`Game` entity in database with `LocalDateTime` = 2020-04-05 21:00:00

Current datetime: 2020-04-05 12:00:00 (do nothing, because current datetime doesn't equal to `Game` datetime)

[9 hours later]

`Game` entity in database (is immutable) with `LocalDateTime` = 2020-04-05 21:00:00

Current datetime: 2020-04-05 21:00:00 (current datetime matches with `Game`'s datetime, so do some action (for example `System.out.println(game)`)).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to schedule a job with annotation `@Scheduled`, which will process data with database using spring data jpa.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=0 * * * *)
@Transactional
public void scheduleGameJob() {
    Optional<Game> game = gameRepo.findById(1L);
    if (game.isPresent()) {
     LocalDateTime gameTime = game.get().getLocalDateTime();
     if (gameTime.equals(LocalDateTime.now())) {
      //do some action (for example System.out.println(game))).
     }
    }
}
```